# How to scan HBase by python in MapReduce Job?

Tags: python, mapreduce, hbase

my program of mapreduce jobs is written by python, and I want to get data from HBase as input. Is there any way to scan the data in HBase table in MapReduce way, such as the TableMapper/Reducer in the native Java implementation. I learned that HappyBase can provide a easy way to interact with HBase, but it only works in client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a pig script that gets the data from HBase and then integrate python either via [streaming](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#stream) or, if you use jython, via [UDFs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#python-udfs)

Comment: Thank you. I am now tring another way: invoke python program in java MapReduce. Which way is more efficient during the processing?

Comment: if you write a fully tuned map-reduce than Java will be better but in most cases a pig script (or some other framework like cascading, Hive etc.) would be more efficient